# FInd two highest values for various rows in MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a MySQL table, *sales*, with this contents:

```
+----+-------+--------+
| id | name  | amount |
+----+-------+--------+
|  1 | Alice |     12 |
|  2 | Bob   |     10 |
|  3 | Alice |     14 |
|  4 | Bob   |      2 |
|  5 | Alice |      6 |
|  6 | Bob   |     23 |
|  7 | Bob   |      5 |
|  8 | Alice |     12 |
+----+-------+--------+
```

For each *name* I want to find the two rows with the highest *amount*. In other words, I want a query that returns this result:

```
+----+-------+--------+
| id | name  | amount |
+----+-------+--------+
|  3 | Alice |     14 |
|  1 | Alice |     12 |
|  6 | Bob   |     23 |
|  2 | Bob   |     10 |
+----+-------+--------+
```

(Only one of rows 1 and 8 should be included in the result. It doesn't matter which.)

How can I do that?

**EDIT**

Row 8 in the table added to clarify the handling of ties.

Comment: If there are ties then what?

Comment: @P.Salmon In that case a random row may be returned.

Comment: If 2nd and 3rd rows contains the same amount does you want: 3 rows in output? 2 rows in output? if last then what row must be skipped?

Comment: @Akina I want 2 rows in output. It doesn't matter which row is discarded.

Comment: Use [GMB's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65250051/10138734) but replace RANK() with ROW_NUMBER().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, just use window functions:

```
select *
from (
    select s.*,
        rank() over(partition by name order by amount desc) rn
    from sales s
) s
where rn <= 2
order by name, amount desc
```

This allows top 2 ties, if any.

In earlier versions, one option uses a subquery for filtering:

```
select *
from sales s
where (select count(*) from sales s1 where s1.name = s.name and s1.amount > s.amount) < 2
order by name, amount desc
```

Comment: If I add another row for Alice with the amount 12, then these queries will return three rows for Alice: One containing 14 and two containing 12. I really only want two rows returned. I doesn't matter which of the "12"-rows is discarded.

Comment: Look OP answer to my comment - ROW_NUMBER() needed, not RANK(). PS. I'd prefer CTE, the query text will be more clear.

Comment: @oz1cz If so then mark the answer as solution.

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach in older versions of MySQL is:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.amount >= (select t2.amount
                   from t t2
                   where t2.name = t.name 
                   order by t2.amount desc
                   limit 1 offset 1
                  );
```

With an index on `(name, amount)`, this might be the fastest approach.

Answer (score -1):

If you're on modern MySQL, `row_number` should be what you're looking for.

```
select
  row_number() over (partition by [name] order by [amount] desc]) [rank], 
  id,
  name, 
  amount
```

This adds the necessary "rank" column, so you just SELECT from that SELECT as your table source:

```
select id, name, amount
from ( -- the above query 
  select
    row_number() over (partition by [name] order by [amount] desc]) [rank], 
    id,
    name, 
    amount
) x
where x.[rank] <= 2
order by [name], [amount] desc
```

C'est tout.

Comment: This is SQL Server syntax which is not applicable to MySQL.

Comment: Not so, according to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number. But sure, vote me down.

Comment: Point me to using square brackets as aliases' quote symbols.

Comment: It's nothing to do with aliases as such (in MSSQL the square brackets are one way to delimit object names). It's been a while since I had to use MySQL, sorry if the bracketes threw you. This doesn't change the fact that `row_number` is the right solution, and better than `rank` (which assigns the same number to peers), according to the documentation I've linked above.